# Mongodb aggregation pipeline is slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database of 30mb size, and it has 300 documents which are stored in a single collection, and their size vary from 1mb to 10kb. I am using the new aggregation framework which comes with **2.6** and I do not have any indexes.

I have an aggregation pipeline as following:

```
1. $match > first query match
2. $project > exclude some fields for efficiency
3. $unwind > unwind one of the arrays
4. $unwind > unwind second array
5. $project > projection to find matching fields among two arrays with $eq
6. $match > same:true
7. $group > put the unwinded arrays together
8. $limit(50)
```

this pipeline above requires **30** seconds. **If I remove $limit, it takes ages.**  My question is:

Database size is only **30MB**, and pipeline is not complicated at all. Why is it taking so long? Any ideas on that?

---

**EDIT**

My schema is as following:

```
{
username: string (max 20 chars
userid : string max 20 chars
userage : string max 20 chars
userobj1: array of objects, length: ~300-500 

// example of userobj1:
    [
       { 
          innerobj1: array of objects, length: ~30-50
          innerobj2: array of objects, length: ~100-200
          userinfo1: string max 20 chars
          userinfo2: string max 20 chars
          userinfo3: string max 20 chars
          userinfo4: string max 20 chars
       } ...
    ]

userobj2: same as userobj1
userobj3: same as userobj1
userobj4: same as userobj1
}
```

this document above has inner objects up to 3-4 levels. Sorry that I cannot provide an example but the alias should be enough. Example query is as following:

```
1. $match: 
    $and : [
             {userobj1: $elemMatch: {userinfo1:a}}, 
             {userobj1: $elemMatch: {userinfo4:b}}
           ]
2. $project {username:1, userid:1, userobj1:1, userobj2:1}
3. $unwind userobj1
4. $unwind userobj2
5. $project 
        {
          username:1, 
          userid:1, 
          userobj1:1, 
          userobj2:1,
          userobj3:1, 
          userobj4:1, 
          "same" : {
              $eq: [ userobj3.userinfo4, userobj4.userinfo4 ]
           }
         }
6. $match {same:true}
7. $group all arrays back
8. limit 50.
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but when you don't care about duplicates, you could try using $push instead of $addToSet. It should be faster because it doesn't have to iterate the whole array to check if the value already exists.

Comment: can you provide a less vague description? I think it would be helpful if we new some of the data and the actual aggregation query.

Comment: @xlembouras I will, @Philipp I tried to play around with group, even putting a single group on `_id` does not help, still 30seconds

Comment: can you share your aggregration query and the schema with a sample document?

Comment: please have a look to the edit

Comment: I suggest that you rewrite the match part to not use `AND` and then add indexes to `userinfo1:a` and `userinfo4:b`. I think that the limit part without the `group` part simplifies your pipeline too much, try running it without the limit.

Comment: good idea, but it is just strange, it is not a big database.. why taking so much have no idea..

Comment: @anvarik: Shard your data.

Comment: :) I am talking about 30 mb

Comment: @xlembouras, you were right, it was because of limit that first query is 0.5 seconds, it is damn slow! I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it looks like a simple answer was never reached and it involves using an expression that was available in 2.6 so it would have worked back then too.   You don't need to do any `$unwind`ing or complex `$map`ping you just need to do a [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) on the two arrays that you want to find a match in.

Using the example data from the very long answer:

```
db.foo.aggregate(
   {$match:{"obj1.a":"a"}},
   {$project:{keep:{$setIntersection:["$obj1.b","$obj2.b"]},obj1:1,obj2:1}},
   {$match:{keep:{$ne:[]}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("588a8206c01d80beca3a8e45"), "obj1" : [ { "a" : "a", "b" : "b" }, { "a" : "a", "b" : "c" } ], "obj2" : [ { "a" : "c", "b" : "b" }, { "a" : "c", "b" : "c" } ], "keep" : [ "b", "c" ] }
```

Only one of the two documents is kept, the one that had two values of "b" in both obj1 and obj2 arrays.

In your original "syntax" the `$project` stage would be

```
 same: {$setIntersection: [ '$userobj3.userinfo4', '$userobj4.userinfo4' ]}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something here that I just don't get about what you are actually trying to do here. So please bear with me on the possible actual questions and answers that I see.

Considering this simplified data set to your case:

```js
{
    "obj1": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "a", "b": "c" }
    ],
    "obj2": [
        { "a": "c", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "c", "b": "c" }
    ]
},
{
    "obj1": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "b" }
    ],
    "obj2": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "c" }
    ]
}
```

---

**Q:** *"Are you not just trying to to match the documents with `{ "a": "a", "b": b" }` in "obj1" and also `{ "b": "b" }` in "object2"?"*

If that is the case then this is just a simple query with `.find()`:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "obj1": {
        "$elemMatch": { "a": "a", "b": "b" }
    },
    "obj2.b": "b"
})
```

Matches only one of those documents that meets the conditions, in this case just the **one**:

```js
{
    "obj1": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "a", "b": "c" }
    ],
    "obj2": [
        { "a": "c", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "c", "b": "c" }
    ]
}
```

---

**Q:** *"Are you possibly trying to find the positions in the array where your conditions are `true`?"*

If so there are some operators available to MongoDB 2.6 that helps you without using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "obj1": {
            "$elemMatch": { "a": "a", "b": "b" }
        },
        "obj2.b": "b"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "obj1": 1,
        "obj2": 1,
        "match1": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$obj1",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$and": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el.a", "a" ] },
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el.b", "b" ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "match2": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$obj2",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$el.b", "b" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Gives you:

```js
{
    "obj1": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "a", "b": "c" }
    ],
    "obj2": [
        { "a": "c", "b": "b" },
        { "a": "c", "b": "c" }
    ],
    "match1" : [
            true,
            false
    ],
    "match2" : [
            true,
            false
    ]
}
```

---

**Q:** *"Or are you possibly trying to "filter" only the matching array elements to those conditions?"*

You can do this with more set operators in MongoDB 2.6 without using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "obj1": {
            "$elemMatch": { "a": "a", "b": "b" }
        },
        "obj2.b": "b"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "obj1": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$obj1",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                         "$cond": [
                           { "$and": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.a", "a" ] },
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.b", "b" ] }
                            ]},
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        },
        "obj2": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$obj2",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.b", "b" ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

And the result:

```js
{
    "obj1": [
        { "a": "a", "b": "b" },
    ],
    "obj2": [
        { "a": "c", "b": "b" },
    ]
}
```

---

The last entry there is the cutest which combines [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) to do some complex filtering of the objects in the array in order to filter just the matches to the conditions. You previously would have to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to get those results.

So it is both [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) that are not required to actually get to any of these results, and those are really killing you. Also your big "pass through" on the "unwound" arrays with [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) suggests trying to get to the end result of one of the above, but in the way you have implemented it would be very costly.

Also try to have an index within one of those arrays for the element to match that is going to reduce your working results down as far as possible. In all cases it's going to improve things even if you cannot have a compound "multi-key" index due to the restrictions there.

Anyhow, hoping that at least something here that either matches your intent or is at least close to what you are trying to do.

---

Since your comments went this way, matching values of "obj1.a" to "obj2.b" without the filtering is not much different to the general cases shown.

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "match": {
            "$size": {
                "$setIntersection": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$obj1",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": { "$concat": ["$$el.a",""] }
                    }},
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$obj2",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": { "$concat": ["$$el.b",""] }
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "$gte": 1 } }
])
```

All simply done without using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

Comment: hey Neil, thanks for your detailed answer. I will try to answer your questions: A1: sorry I forgot to add a `$match`, I do a `{same:true}` match after projection, and the reason is that I need to return the documents that only have that inner equality. A2:position does not matter.. A3: yes I d like to filter, and without using $where. What I would like to add is that if I exclude `$limit` I am hitting 16mb barrier, and if I try to fetch all of them with the new aggregation it takes ages. Isn't it weird? I have only a 30mb of data...

Comment: @anvarik My point here is that one of those things seems to be what you are trying to do but you are going the long way about it. The basic concept followed through is that your logic on looking for the same value in "userinfo4" is the same as adding that to the initial $match condition as I show. So then you either 1: Want the whole documents back, 2: Want the positions back, 3: Filter the contents of the array to the matching documents. Those are the things shown. It is very unclear what you expect as a result, hence the format of the answer.

Comment: I totally understand. But please have a look to my steps 3 to 6. First I am doing two `$unwind`s on two `array of objects`, and after that I am doing a `$project` with `$eq`. The reason is that I need two values to be equal where I only know the keys. In your example what I want is   `$where:'obj1.a = obj2.b'`. I see that you are proposing ways to eliminate first 4-5 stages to boost the performance, but probably I did not explain the case well. Sorry for lack of information.

Comment: @anvarik I think you are still missing it. `$eq: [ userobj1.userinfo4, userobj2.userinfo4 ]` is what you have in your code `{$match: { "userobj1.userinfo4": b, "userobj2.userinfo4": b }}` does exactly the same thing, which is what I am saying from the start. `obj1.a == obj2.b` is different to your code you have shown. But if you want that, it is just a variation on the above which I can write out if that is what you need.

Comment: but in `{$match: { "userobj1.userinfo4": b, "userobj2.userinfo4": b }}` you know that these two fields should be `b`, I don't know whether it is `b` or `c` etc. that is why I do `$eq: [ userobj1.userinfo4, userobj2.userinfo4 ]`, and that is why I unwind. Do you think this is the bottleneck? I don't know a way to do that without unwinding and projecting

Comment: @anvarik I say that because you are supplying that $match condition right at the head of your pipeline where you tell it you want `"userobj1.userinfo4": b` so it stands to reason to just supply the same value to match. Rather than thinking through how to answer me, take the time to read your own question and all of this answer again. Your equality match is redundant given your match conditions.  Or otherwise specify "clearly" if you actually want whatever the "userinfo4" values in elements for both arrays to match without any filtering as you have done.

Comment: the first match is completely independent than the second one. Second equality should be always there, and unfortunately I cannot change the document structure. If you can help me on resolving the second match, i will accept that

Comment: @anvarik 5 minutes was not nearly enough time for you to digest this. Please read again and clearly answer my last question from my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54972/discussion-between-anvarik-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: first match: `"userobj1.userinfo4": b`, second equality match: `userobj3.a == userobj4.b`; they don't have anything in common. The key value names are simply mockups

Comment: @anvarik Your still not reading this correctly or even the example I added to your comment about matching the equality of matching different properties. Please read it back. Please actually try the examples adapted to your actual situation. Just trying to help you understand a concept you do not seem to be grasping. It's all there if you read it. If you still don't believe so then please edit your question to make your intentions clear.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience, glad that you always really try to help. I will re-read all the comments again

Comment: @anvarik I am just intrigued as to what answered your question. Was it that you actually needed the same values in two properties without filtering, or did the lightbulb click to what I was saying about matching on the same property value?

Comment: hi neil, the problem was $unwinding stage as you have mentioned, if you have like 500 - 600 length of two arrays and unwind both of them, you will get like 600^2 times remaining document size which was the problem, I took some time to understand your last entry, which did the trick. Final question: what do you use as a mongo ui client? I used to use robomongo, but they don't support 2.6... now playing with monguvue

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it takes that long because there are no indexes so it does a full collection scan every time it needs a record.

Try adding an index on `userinfo1:a` and I think you will see a good performance gain. I will also recommend that you remove the `AND` syntax from the `match` phase and rewrite it as a list.

I think it would be really helpful for both you and the question to give us the output of the aggregation's explain. In mongo 2.6 you can have [explain in aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate).

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ ... stages ...], { explain:true } )
```

Comment: nah I tried adding indexes to the first matching stage, didnt help. Maybe it is because of long pipeline? Have no idea ..